# Question about grouping or separating functions / methods that are alike

Tags: function, methods, correctness

I'll take a real example I have to implement in a program I'm coding:

I have a database that has the score of every game bowled in the past three years in a bowling center. With a GUI, you can choose to either search for the best score on each lane, search for the best score between two dates, for the best score for each week, etc.

I'm wondering what the best way to implement this is. Should I code something like this:

```
public Vector<Scores> grabMaxScores(sortType, param1, param2)
{
    if(sortType.equals("By lane"))
        ...
    else if(sortType.equals("Between given dates")
        ...
}
```

Or is it more appropriate to code different methods for each type and call the correct one in the listener?

```
public Vector<Scores> grabMaxScoresBetweenDates(startDate, endDate)
{
    ...
}

public Vector<Scores> grabMaxScoresByLane(minLane, maxLane)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm not necessarily asking for this particular problem, it's just a question I find asking myself often when I'm coding multiple methods that are alike where the principle is the same, but the parameters are different.

I can see there are good reasons to use each of them, but I want to know if there is a "more correct" or standard way of coding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion, I would prefer your second option over the first. This is because you have the opportunity to be precise about things like the types of the parameters. For example, `minLane` and `maxLane` may just be integers, but `startDate` and `endDate` could very well be `Date` objects. It's often nicer if you can actually specify what you expect, as it reduces the need for such things as casting and range checks, etc. Also, I would find it more readable, as the function names just say what you are trying to do.

However, I may have an alternative idea, which is kind of a variation on your first example (I actually got this inspiration from Java's Comparator, in case you're familiar with that). Rather than pass a string as the first argument, pass some sort of `Selector` object. `Selector` would be the name of a class or a interface, which would look something like so (in Java):

```
interface Selector {
    public void select(Score next);
    public Score getBest( );
}
```

If the `select` method "likes" the value of `next` which is given to it, it can store the value for later. If it doesn't like it, it can simply discard it, and keep whatever value it already has. After all the data is processed, the best value will be left over, and can be requested by calling `getBest`. Of course, you can alter the interface to suit your particular needs (e.g. it seems like you might be expecting more than one value to be retrieved. Also, generics might help a lot as well).

The reason I like this idea is that now your function is very general purpose. In order to add new functionality, you don't need to add functions, and you don't need to modify any functions you already have. Instead, the *user* of your code can simply define their own implementation of `Selector` as they see fit. This allows your code to be far more compositional, which makes it easier to use. The only inconvenience is the need to define implementations of `Selector`, though, you could also provide several default ones.

Comment: This seems like a great idea, I didn't know you could do that. I'm not familiar with the selector concept, but I'll be sure to read up on it as it seems like the best possible solution and it will probably help me a lot in the future too. I'm coding this application in Java, so I shouldn't have any problem with implementing it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the Selector correctly, so sorry if what I'm going to ask doesn't make sense, but wouldn't having to pass different selectors depending on how you want to search for data be kind of the same as using different methods? The idea is great, but I don't see why it's "better" in the sense that you have to modify code for new cases anyway (create a new selector instead of a new method)

Comment: The big reason for using patterns like these is that users of your code will never be restricted in what they can do. If you choose to implement a new method for everything, then everyone else will only be able to do whatever *you* have thought of (which won't be everything). Even if this code is only intended to be used by yourself, I think it's worthwhile to write code as though someone else will use it as well, in which case extensibility is highly important.

Comment: Just to be clear (I'll accept your answer after this), the pattern you're talking about is if another programmer wants to modify my code to add a new functionality, he's only going to have pass a new Selector object to my method instead of having to define a new one /modify the old method. Isn't it as much work to create a new class to "Select" the correct value than it is to create a new method? What you're saying makes sense and it seems like it would be cleaner, but I don't see how it makes the program more expandable since with both ways you could create a new function (though differently)

Comment: Sure, making a class is just as much work as making a method. The point is that any programmer can create a class, but you are the only one who can add a method. If you want more information, I believe this an example of the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_Pattern).

Comment: Just for a bit more reference, a key concept in good object-oriented design is the [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), which the Strategy Pattern was intended to satisfy. This is the actual concept I have been trying to put my finger on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it! I'm going to read up on those principles, it seems like it will help me a lot in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have used would also work. But if you want to add some new functionality like "get lowest scores on Friday evening", you will need to add one more function, which kinda not so good thing to do.

As you have already have the data in a database you can generate database queries which would fetch the required results and display. So you need not modify your code every time.